# File path manipulation by string.Substring

Tags: c#

I can't understand these 2 lines and why we cut the root with substring:

```
root=AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
C.FileName = root.Substring(0, root.Length - 10) + "etat_selection_formula.rpt";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should strongly consider using the System.IO.Path class for manipulation of file paths, rather than direct string manipulation.  It is aware of the semantics of UNC paths and won't tie you to the original (clearly short-sighted) implementation.  What happens when the first part of the path isn't exactly 10 characters?  Your whole application breaks just because someone moved or renamed a folder.

MSDN documentation (including usage examples) here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do it normally.

Someone is just using that to replace another report path or page name.

In my opinion it is bad code, and you should have the base path stored in a constant if you need it. Would be a lot more readable that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
root=AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; 
C.FileName = root.Substring(0, root.Length - 10) + "etat_selection_formula.rpt";
```

First line just get's the directory where your app is running.
Second line removes the last 10 characters from that and adds the name of some report ("etat_...").

As of why you do this ... well if you don't know - me cannot either.
Best guess: you want to get one directory up (in some fixed path) and then append your standard report.

If so: bad practice - you should rethink this.

Comment: just make sure to not depend on the place where you app will be installed. At the very least make the folders where you put your external resources a setting you can change without recompiling your code - for example with app.settings/config files